# show a list menu on hover of a div

Tags: javascript, html, jsx

I have a function which maps an array of items and shows as an  in react js.

```
 const getTrolleyItems=(tr,id)=>{
    const listItems =
    tr.typesOfItems.map((i,index) => (
    <li style={{lineHeight:'1.5rem',textAlign:'left',listStyleType: 'circle',float:'left',color:"black"}} key={index}>{i.name}</li>
    ))
    return (
    <div style={{lineHeight:'1.5rem',color:"black",display:'flex',marginTop:'0.5rem',justifyContent:'center'}}>{`${listItems.length} items`}</div>
    );
    
    }
```

my intention is to show the items on hovering the div elements which displays the list count.How is it possible